# How to make fluid layout using Bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

I'm switching to bootstrap4 today. I enabled flexbox in `_variables.scss` yet I'm confused about what exactly is flexbox capabilities of bootstrap4. For example

1. How can I make `flex-direction:column`?
2. Is it possible to have a column with fluid width? `flex-grow`?

I have this markup to build a full height sidebar layout

```
<div class="flex-col">

 <div class="flex-row" id="topnav">
  <div class="flex"> <!-- this will grow -->
    Brand
  </div>

  <div> left navbar</div>
 </div>

 <div class=" flex flex-row"> <!--flex expand to fill full height -->
  <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  <div class="flex">Content</div> <!--take rest of row space-->
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I achieve this with bootstrap flexbox?

Comment: How is this too broad ? Im asking for specific demo code as an example of bootstrap framework usage.

Answer (score 4):

Read the docs at: http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/

You just need to enable flexbox, and the `row`, `col-*` use flexbox. BS3 uses `flex-wrap` and `flex-direction:row`, instead of `flex-direction:column` The new [auto-layout columns](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/flexbox-grid/#auto-layout-columns) use flex-grow to consume the remaining space in a row.

```
<div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
            4
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-3">
            3
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs">
           grow
       </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/rZNj0SSRmi

***Update***

In **Bootstrap 4 alpha 6**, flexbox is now the default so it no longer needs to be enabled. There are also new [flexbox utilities](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) for various properties like `flex-column`, `justify-content-`, `align-items-` etc.. The auto-layout columns can still be used to "grow` width or height.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 sidebar">Sidebar</div>
        <div class="col">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Bootstrap 4 A6 example fluid layout](http://www.codeply.com/go/IWSNETLUUT)